# MySQL query - show results that are not in another table

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT lesson.id, p1.first_name, p1.surname, start_time, instrument.name 
FROM  lesson, person AS p1, person AS p2, instrument, invoice_lesson
WHERE lesson.student = p1.id
AND   lesson.teacher = p2.id
AND   instrument.id  = lesson.instrument_id
ORDER BY surname
```

However, I would like to modify it so that it only shows results where `lesson.id` is not in the table `invoice_lesson.lesson_id`.  Is this a correlated query? How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with an outer join:

```
SELECT lesson.id, p1.first_name, p1.surname, start_time, instrument.name 
FROM  lesson l JOIN person p1 ON l.student = p1.id
JOIN person p2 ON l.teacher = p2.id
JOIN instrument i ON i.id = l.instrument_id
LEFT JOIN invoice_lesson il ON l.id = il.lesson_id
WHERE il.lesson_id IS NULL
ORDER BY surname
```

This approach will be much faster than the correlated subquery approach.

Comment: the first line needed altering to match you aliases though ;) thx

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way:

```
SELECT lesson.id, p1.first_name, p1.surname, start_time, instrument.name 
FROM  lesson, person AS p1, person AS p2, instrument, invoice_lesson
WHERE lesson.student = p1.id
AND   lesson.teacher = p2.id
AND   instrument.id  = lesson.instrument_id
AND   lesson.id NOT IN (SELECT lesson_id FROM invoice_lesson)
ORDER BY surname
```

Might not exactly be the quickest one :)

Tomasz Kopczuk

Comment: You really should be using a join, rather than a sub select.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_join.asp):

```
 SELECT lesson.id, p1.first_name, p1.surname, start_time, instrument.name 
 FROM  lesson, person AS p1, person AS p2, instrument, invoice_lesson
 JOIN  invoice_lesson
 ON    lession.id = invoice_lession.lesson_id
 WHERE lesson.student = p1.id
 AND   lesson.teacher = p2.id
 AND   instrument.id  = lesson.instrument_id
 ORDER BY surname
```

Comment: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'invoice_lesson'